# Batch script to look for a pattern and display an alert on Windows 7

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm looking for how to look for a pattern on a txt file and if that pattern exists, then display an alert on the Windows' action center or send an email.

It should be something like `if [ $(grep -ci error log) -ne 0 ]; then sendmail; else rm log; fi` but on Windows realm.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`findstr`](http://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html) command for that.

Example:

```
findstr /s /c:"error log" *.log
IF %ERRORLEVEL% == 0 ( 
   REM ---- FOUND ERROR ENTRIES (!) -----

   [SEND E-MAIL HERE]
)
```

To send an e-mail, you will need some external utility, like [this one](http://sourceforge.net/projects/blat/).